# Pence as president?

Tags: donald-trump, russian-federation, impeachment, vice-president, mike-pence

If it turns out that trump was elected due to collusion with Russia, does that mean that it was actually a Clinton win due to cheating in the trump camp? And if so, can v.p. pence then be president (if trump is impeached) if he was never REALLY elected with trump? Do we have any rules in place for this situation?

I can't seem to find an answer so thanks in advance if you know the answer :)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  The question here is whether a bogus election, **if generally understood as such**, has any more meaning than an episode of a fictitious TV show.  That is, we obviously cannot impeach [Frank Underwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Underwood_(House_of_Cards)) because he's not real -- not even if *House of Cards* were presented as a documentary, or even if the leading man were swapped out with some actor from "Reality TV".

Answer (score -3):

If Trump is forced to resign in the next four years then Vice President Mike Pence will take his place in the Oval Office. In contrast to Trump’s maverick behaviour and posturing as a Washington outsider, Pence has strong party links and is regarded by many Republicans as a safe pair of hands.

Here for more information on the procedure:

http://litigation.findlaw.com/legal-system/presidential-impeachment-the-legal-standard-and-procedure.html?version=2

Edit:

Also, it would be one thing to find that Trump was colliding with Russia, but unless you could ALSO prove that Mike Pence knew about the collusion then Mike Pence would simply step in, it's simple as that.

Comment: Does anyone have anything to say about my answer?

Comment: I have the gist of how impeachment works, president gets impeached, vp becomes president. I'm not asking about that. What I meant was, if there is actual evidence (not suspicions by non-investigative bodies and/ or news media) that trump never actually won the election, do we just impeach him or is there some precedent for this SPECIFIC situation?

Comment: Not a downvoter, but I'm not sure why you would expect people to register their relatives as deceased, that burden falls on the state. Pointing out conspiracy theories from the right doesn't itself invalidate conspiracy theories from the left.

Comment: Allegations on both side don't magically cancel each other out. Republican claims of improper voting by illegals or in blue states has zero evidence, period. The first sentence of your last paragraph is about the only good part of your answer.

Comment: 1) You shouldn't answer off-topic questions as they will either be closed (and thus shouldn't have answers) or edited to make them on-topic (thus invalidating your answer) 2) "Others also cheated" isn't relevant to the question or an answer 3) You didn't provide any reliable sources for it (which makes sense as there aren't any; it's just an unrelated nonsense conspiracy theory).

Comment: @Jeff not saying they do mate

Comment: @Charlie then what is your point in including them in your answer, mate?